# docker container with multiple tcp ports

Tags: docker

I created a docker container based on the github link - https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker

and noticed 3 ports being displayed and one port being mapped to the host.

I understand port 2181 which is been exposed from the container to the host system.

but what are these 3 ports - 22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp ..If these are not exposed to the host system why they are being displayed.

```
a5779d08be33        wurstmeister/zookeeper                                                             "/bin/sh -c '/usr/..."   40 minutes ago      Up 3 minutes        22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   kafkadocker_zookeeper_1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After pulling the image if you run below command

```
docker history --no-trunc wurstmeister/zookeeper | grep EXPOSE
... EXPOSE 2181/tcp 2888/tcp 3888/tcp 
... EXPOSE map[22/tcp:{}]
```

So you see that the Dockerfile used to build this image has mentioned that port `2181, 2888, 3888, 22` are supposed to be exposed.

`docker ps` will show you the ports which are mentioned by the image metadata and also the one you mapped.

Let's say I run the below command

```
docker run --rm nginx
```

`docker ps` will show

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
e39964ca9bb8        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   2 seconds ago       Up 1 second         80/tcp              suspicious_jones
```

This tells the image metadata indicates that port 80 is what the program inside the container may be listening to. Now if I run the same container as below

```
docker run -p 8080:8080  --rm nginx
```

`docker ps` will show

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
93df718d1d86        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   26 seconds ago      Up 25 seconds       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   confident_bassi
```

So it is a combination of image port metadata and the ports you actually mapped. This metadata comes in handy when we use the `-P` flag

```
docker run -P --rm nginx
```

Now `docker ps` gives us

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES

bf70d3212ee9        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   1 second ago        Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:32768->80/tcp   hungry_keller
```

As you can see every port mentioned in the image metadata automatically gets mapped to a available port on the host